# Rotating an image about center in CSS?

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform, image-rotation

I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "container">
                <img class = "image img-fluid" src = "advertisement.png">
                <img class = "image img-fluid reset" src = "blue.png">
                <img class = "image img-fluid reset" src = "green.png">
                <img class = "image img-fluid reset" src = "brown.png">
                <img class = "image img-fluid reset" src = "red.png">
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where style.css is:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 840px;
    height: 600px;
}

.reset{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

Before adding the reset class to each of the blue, green, brown, and red images, I have something like this:
[image]

Note that the individual m&ms images are only the size of the m&m's themselves, i.e. they're not huge with an invisible background.

Now, my issue is that, when I try and add the 180 degree rotation, rather than rotating about their center, the m&ms do something like this:
[image]

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a snippet or fiddle ?

Comment: Because you made the `.image` larger than it supposed to be. I don't know how did you cut the image off, but it looks like you just cut the m&m's directly from the original image and left a lot of transparent spaces.

Comment: I think the issue is with `position absolute` due to which its disturbing the rotation as you are using `absolute` without defining `top` `left` `right`

Comment: can you use any site like codepen or sandbox and upload your snippet there with the assets so that i can look into it?

Comment: I think hao is right,  I will try to fix it and post it to a codepen if I can't, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

*You are not restricting the size of the div.

In fact you don't need the div at all, you can just apply the class to the image:*

```css
.world
{
-webkit-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
-o-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
-ms-animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
animation: spin1 2s infinite linear;
    display: block;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin1 {
0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-keyframes spin1 {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<img class="world" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Erioll_world_2.svg/256px-Erioll_world_2.svg.png"/>
```